# Problems installing/importing XLConnect and rJava in RStudio

Tags: java, r, rjava, xlconnect

Hope to get some help here. I just installed R-Studio (Version 1.3.1093) and tried to install some packages (e.g XLConnect). I got an error message and it seems like it's a Java issue (see code below, JRE and R version below). But since I'm not an expert I cannot really figure out what's the problem just by reading the error message. Can anyone help me?

**CODE:**

```
> install.packages("XLConnect")
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/XLConnect_1.0.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 22898238 bytes (21.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 21.8 MB
The downloaded binary packages are in
/var/folders/jc/vklzwn9d0bn5v_wcqdcnr_880000gn/T//RtmpbfPNaD/downloaded_packages
```

**CODE:**

```
> library(XLConnect)
```

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnect’:
.onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'rJava' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
Aufruf: fun(libname, pkgname)
Fehler: JVM could not be found
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen:

1: In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  Ausführung von Kommando '/usr/libexec/java_home' ergab Status 1
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  Cannot find JVM library 'NA/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
Install Java and/or check JAVA_HOME (if in doubt, do NOT set it, it will be detected)
```

**R-Version:**

> version
> _
> platform       x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
> arch           x86_64
> os             darwin17.0
> system         x86_64, darwin17.0
> status
> major          4
> minor          0.3
> year           2020
> month          10
> day            10
> svn rev        79318
> language       R
> version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
> nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out

**JRE-Version:**

```
 /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)
```

[image]